# Do we have to implement syspolicy_purge_history job in case of azure database, as there is no msdb

Tags: azure, azure-functions, database-migration, sql-function, sql-job

I migrated from `sql server` to Azure db.

While migrating I found a job named `syspolicy_purge_history`, do I also need to implement it on Azure db?

As I found the `syspolicy_purge_history` job is targeting `msdb`, but I could not found `msdb` on Azure. A guidance will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `syspolicy_purge_history` job in case of azure database and `msdb` not available for Azure SQL Data Warehouse in your case its applicable and supported all version of [msdb database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/msdb-database?view=sql-server-ver16)

Syspolicy purge history is the default job that deletes data that is older than the number of days specified in the HistoryRetentionInDays property of Policy Management. This prevents unnecessary space consumption in the MSDB system database.

For your Reference:

[sp_syspolicy_purge_history (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-syspolicy-purge-history-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

[Migrate SQL Server to Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dms/tutorial-sql-server-to-azure-sql)